# can we use camera for real time face detection in android app without having a capturing option in them

Tags: android, camera

I am working on an android application which detect faces in real time and for that i have to make a camera to scan faces but i do not want to give a capture facility in that camera and after detection the next option of filters will come automatically. So, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course,it is possible and OpenCV do that all for you... follow the given links:

**1. [Demo:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwI-n3sI8ec) 

2.  [OpenCV sample code](http://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-samples.html)

3. [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/face-detection)**

Thanks,